# Setting parameter names and defaults in method created at runtime

Tags: python

I need to give an automatically constructed method positional and default parameters. If I didn't care about the parameter names or defaults I would have the method take *args and **kwargs. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do (note that

```
def make_method(params):
    # Create method that's parameters are defined in params.
    return method

params = {'param1': 'default_value', 'param2': None}
method = make_method(params)
```

For each non-None value I want to create a positional argument in method and for each None value I want to create a default parameter.

The problem is that I don't know how to set the parameter names and default values at runtime. I don't want to use *args and **kwars for method since it'd be better to have the signature correct when using help() etc.. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Wow. Not sure why you'd **need** to do this, but it's an interesting question (to which I don't have an answer I'm afraid).

Comment: Day, I'm trying to automatically build a program from a configuration file that contains a list of method names, parameters, parameter defaults, and a specification of what the method returns. Everything is working well except that I want the help() function to be more helpful and I want the user to be able use default values.

Comment: I think params shouldn't be a dict because you can't iterate in in predictable order when generating arguments. Perhaps a list of tuples with arg specifications is a better design.

Comment: @Pavel Repin, I agree, but I don't have control over the format of the parameters. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a HACK! Also I am not sure I understand how to generate kwargs based on what you asked. But this is a start. Although, I am not sure if it's a good start :)

```
def make_method(params):
    def impl(*args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff with args & kwargs
        print "I was called with {args} and {kwargs}".format(
            args=args,
            kwargs=kwargs)
        pass
    name = 'some_name'
    scope = dict(__impl=impl)
    exec """\
def {name}({pos_arg_defs}):
    'Very helpful function.'
    return __impl({pos_arg_names})
""".format(name=name,
           pos_arg_defs=', '.join('='.join((k, repr(v)))
                                  for k, v in params.iteritems()
                                  if v is not None),
           pos_arg_names=', '.join(k
                                   for k, v in params.iteritems()
                                   if v is not None)) in scope
    return scope[name]
```

Here's the some REPL output:

```
>>> help(make_method(dict(foo=42, bar=None, zomg='abc')))
Help on function some_name:

some_name(zomg='abc', foo=42)
    Very helpful function.
```