Define default arguments using a dict
I have an unusual situation where a dict of keyword-type argument defaults, the_defaults, is created before a function my_function is defined:
the_defaults = {'kwarg_a': 1, 'kwarg_b': 2}
def my_function(my_args = the_defaults):
  print(my_args['kwarg_a'])
  print(my_args['kwarg_b'])

This code is ugly because my function body has to address entries of my_args instead of using local variables.
Is there any way to avoid this?
I am imagining a dynamic function header def my_function(**kwargs=**the_defaults): [...] but this is obviously meaningless.

Are you expecting to be able to change the dictionary and have that affect the function? That won't work because default values are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called. So the defaults won't be dynamic.

The defaults don't need to be dynamic.

Are you sure that the first snippet works? I don't recall being able to use attribute lookups for dictionary keys.

Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560051/setting-parameter-names-and-defaults-in-method-created-at-runtime, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158051/dynamically-define-the-keyword-arguments-to-a-function

Oops, now it's something I've tested working. Thanks, both those links are exactly what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately they both look pretty demanding, which suggests to me the approach in the question body is the most maintainable, unfortunately.

What's wrong with def my_function(kwarg_a=1, kwarg_b=2): ... if you expect to access kwarg_a and kwarg_b as local variables, in which case the names are predetermined and don't need to be dynamically defined with a dict? Please clarify your actual use case.

I don't think you can do precisely what you want, but you can use the dictionary argument approach and then merge it with the default:
def my_function(params: dict = {})
    params = the_defaults | params
    # rest of code

